# Why naked Python decorators (without @) do not generate compiler error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just a mistype: I forgot to add @ before property decorator. Lost approx 1 hour to find out what went wrong. Here is an example:

```py
class Woo(object):
    @property
    def success(self):
        return True

    property
    def failure(self):
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    woo = Woo()
    print(f'success={woo.success}')
    print(f'failure={woo.failure}')
    print(f'It\'s fine to call failure()={woo.failure()}')
```

The result is:

```
success=True
failure=<bound method Woo.failure of <__main__.Woo object at 0x0000016050D4F6D8>>
It's fine to call failure()=False
```

I'm wondering why Python compiler allows "naked decorator" (e.g. property without decorator prefix @) in syntax and what does it mean semantically.

Comment: what is a decorator but a function at the end of the day. the `@` is just syntactic sugar to shorten what we have to type out.

Comment: Because it isn't any sort of compile time error. A decorator is just an object, the syntax is just sugar for `def some_func()...;   some_func = decorator (some_func)`. You can always just reference a defined variable with no effect. i.e `x = 0` then simply `x` is perfectly valid (albeit pointless) python code

Answer (score 8):

It's perfectly legal to have a symbol floating around without any purpose, similar to this:

```
a = 1
a  # Perfectly legal, although a thorough linter* will cause a warning
```

In your example, it's just a top-level reference to the `property` class that isn't used for anything, similar to if you had:

```
class MyClass:
    a = 1

    a  # Legal, but causes a warning since it has no purpose
    def meth(self):
        pass

    1  # Also legal but useless
    def another_meth(self):
        pass
```

It isn't being treated as a decorator; it's being treated as a plain reference to the `property` class in a context where it isn't used for anything.

---

`*` Pycharm gives the warning `Statement seems to have no effect`.

Comment: Side question: what IDE/linter gives you a warning for that? I'm using Pylama and it doesn't warn about a missing `@` specifically but does say "E301 expected 1 blank line, found 0 [pep8]"

Comment: @wjandrea Pycharm gives "Statement seems to have no effect". I highly recommend Pycharm unless you want something lightweight. I've used it, IntelliJ and Webstorm for like ~4-5 years now. They're an excellent set of IDEs (but **heavy**).

Comment: I used both PyScripter and Visual Studio (which sucks now at 5 mins delay for Intellisense)

Comment: @RemigijusPankevičius I've never heard of PyScripter, but VS has always annoyed me. It's intolerably slow unless you have a great computer to run it on.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Wow you weren't kidding, Pycharm recommends 4GB free RAM. That's not gonna happen on my dinky old laptop. I'll stick with Atom. Thanks for the recommendation though!

Comment: @wjandrea I recommend even more. I used to have a 4GB Surface Pro 4. Pycharm/IntelliJ + Chrome pretty much depleted 90% of available memory. I'm on an 8GB SP8 now, and it runs beautifully. 8GB minimum on the system I think if you're doing any sort of multitasking.

Answer (score 5):

Any callable can be a decorator, callables are themselves objects, any value can be an expression, any expression can be a statement, and a class declaration can contain arbitrary statements (including things like `if`, `for`, `try`, etc.). There is no error in syntax.

"Decorators" are not some separate data type, nor are they compiler pragmas; they are sugar for a higher-order function applied to a class or function immediately after definition, that is,

```
@property
def spam():
    pass
```

is the same as

```
def spam():
    pass
spam = property(spam)
```

So the callable must take the defined function/class as its argument to work as a decorator.

But `property` is also a perfectly valid statement in its own right.

```
property
```

Statements are instructions, but expressions are calculations that evaluate to a value. Expressions can have side effects in Python, which is why they can be statements on their own (when used this way their value is discarded). It so happens that your `property` statement has no side effects, so it doesn't really do anything when used this way. A good linter might complain, but it's not an error.

Answer (score 4):

In cases like that we can take a look at generated AST (using [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html))

```py
import ast

tree = ast.parse("""class Woo(object):
 @property
 def success(self):
     return True

 property
 def failure(self):
     return False""")
 print(ast.dump(tree))
```

output is

```py
Module(body=[ClassDef(name='Woo', 
                      bases=[Name(id='object', ctx=Load())], 
                      keywords=[], 
                      body=[FunctionDef(name='success', 
                                        args=arguments(args=[arg(arg='self', annotation=None)], 
                                                       vararg=None, 
                                                       kwonlyargs=[], 
                                                       kw_defaults=[], 
                                                       kwarg=None, 
                                                       defaults=[]), 
                                        body=[Return(value=NameConstant(value=True))], 
                                        decorator_list=[Name(id='property', ctx=Load())], 
                                        returns=None), 
                            Expr(value=Name(id='property', ctx=Load())), 
                            FunctionDef(name='failure', 
                                        args=arguments(args=[arg(arg='self', annotation=None)], 
                                                       vararg=None, 
                                                       kwonlyargs=[], 
                                                       kw_defaults=[], 
                                                       kwarg=None, 
                                                       defaults=[]),
                                        body=[Return(value=NameConstant(value=False))], 
                                        decorator_list=[], 
                                        returns=None)], 
                      decorator_list=[])])
```

so as we can see in `Woo` class defintion body there are

- `success` function definition decorated with `property`

```py
FunctionDef(name='success',
            args=arguments(args=[arg(arg='self', annotation=None)],
                           vararg=None,
                           kwonlyargs=[],
                           kw_defaults=[],
                           kwarg=None,
                           defaults=[]),
            body=[Return(value=NameConstant(value=True))],
            decorator_list=[Name(id='property', ctx=Load())],
            returns=None)
```

- expression which loads `property` object in current namespace

```py
Expr(value=Name(id='property', ctx=Load()))
```

- `failure` function definition without any decorators (note `decorator_list=[]`)

```py
FunctionDef(name='failure',
            args=arguments(args=[arg(arg='self', annotation=None)],
                           vararg=None,
                           kwonlyargs=[],
                           kw_defaults=[],
                           kwarg=None,
                           defaults=[]),
            body=[Return(value=NameConstant(value=False))],
            decorator_list=[],
            returns=None)
```

so there is no decorating in the second case but separate expression without effect (which can be anything else, like raw literal definition, modern IDEs like PyCharm helps a lot with searching for such cases) and function definition.

By "expression without effect" I mean that it doesn't affect class definition in any way: doesn't create a member or change other members.

Comment: Do you mean that I've got a member named 'property' in my class Woo?

Comment: Bravo. This is instructive more broadly than the question. Suggestion: Pretty-print the outputs.

Comment: @RemigijusPankevičius: to have a member there should be an assignment like `property = property`

Answer (score 0):

Decorators are just fancy functions, so you wrote it's name but didn't call it.  I can call `print(property)` and I get `<class 'property'>`